# What is killing my battery?

Tags: iphone, battery, charging, ios

I have an iPhone XS (bought brand-new, About section says limited warranty until 14 april 2020, the date I bought it) running iOS 13.2.3 When I took it out of the box it was running iOS 12 and I enrolled to iOS 13 on beta 6 and I kept updating betas when they came out. My battery is now on 90% of health which seems an excessive wear-off for 7 months. My charging habits are as follows:

- One hour in the morning via CarPlay (after being left overnight a bit over 20%)
- One hour in the afternoon via CarPlay (usually being between 30% and 70% due to the daily use)
- Almost never left charging overnight (except one or two times but definitely not something repetitive)
- Almost never left battery completely empty (as above, except one or two times)
- For two or three months I used a wireless charger during the morning and I ocassionally do if I use the phone a bit more
- I scarcely play games in the phone (say one or two times a month, while charging. The phone heats more than usual but it seems normal to me)
- I use my phone for navigation, calls, social media, photography and messaging apps, with some apps doing background work to upload photos. iOS backup to iCloud is disabled (although I back up via iTunes weekly or more frequent)
- I do not expose my phone to extreme temperature changes
- The phone averages 30 hours of screen on per week
- I use the original cable and two other ones that I bought from Amazon which claim to be "made for iPhone": one is Amazon basics and the other one is third party, the price made me think it is legit. However, I charge the phone the most while on CarPlay which is done with the original, shipped within the box. Those two cables are used almost exclusively on weekends.

I should mention that during a span of two weeks or so I updated to iOS 13.2.2 that shipped a bug which depleted the battery faster than normal (in adittion to the two charges, I had to add a third one in between because the phone dropped 30% overnight in airplane mode, which was fixed in iOS 13.2.3)

I do not believe this wear-off pattern is normal. Is there something in the listed above (which seems normal to me) killing my battery?

**EDIT:** adding battery info as reported by iBackupBot

[image: info]

Comment: What do you mean by killing? You don‘t mention that the battery doesn‘t last as long as it did, so based on what do assume something is hurting the battery?

Comment: I mean killing as in the battery health as reported by the system is lower. It doesn't matter if I notice or not, something is doing nasty things with my battery and I want to find out.

Comment: @nohillside in addition, I mentioned that the drop seemed steep for me (10% in seven months)

Comment: do you have a desktop or laptop mac?

Comment: if you have a desktop or laptop computer there is an app called Coconut Battery which you can run with your iPhone connected to your computer, This app will scan your battery and tell you its status.  Coconut can be found here: https://www.coconut-flavour.com/coconutbattery/

Comment: @jmh no, I don't have access to a mac. Is that a Mac only app? What info does it show that I can't see in the Settings app?

Comment: it runs on a Windows machine as well.  I don't have Catalina so it may show nothing which you don't have.  There may be an iOS app that does it now.  Coconut Battery has been around since 2005 but has been updated often.  It gives you Full Charge Capacity and Design Capacity and cycle count.  The app is free I think.

Comment: @jmh sadly I was unable to find a version able to be run on Windows, although I found an alternative that provided me the same information that seems to provide Coconut and attached that info.

Answer (score 1):

No, there's nothing in that list which is "killing" your battery. The battery degrades during normal use - that's not preventable and to be expected.

Batteries are not all alike. Some degrade faster than others - you cannot say that the battery capacity shrinks x.xx% per year in general and expect that exact number on every phone.

Apple [states](https://support.apple.com/en-gb/HT208387) that the battery is designed to retain up to 80% of its original capacity at 500 complete charge cycles under normal conditions. You're still well above 80%.

Having 90% capacity after 222 charge cycles seems to be quite alright - i.e. it is likely that you’ll be at approx. 80% percent after 500 charge cycles.

Comment: I am aware that battery degradation is a normal thing but losing 10% seemed a lot excessive to me and I thought it was a consequence of a bad practice with my battery

Comment: No, what you describe is not bad practice. My own iPhone XS is at 87% capacity right now... if your capacity continues to drop at the same rate so you’re below 80% before 500 charge cycles, I would contact Apple or the place you bought it. Would be good to include the number of cycles in your question if you know it.

Comment: I added the info about cycles. It seems I'm at 222 cycles

Comment: Sounds alright to me!